# Callback is returning undefined when called in a get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I can console log both `results.data.features` and `results.data.features[0].center` when I console `results.data.features[0].center` it shows the data for the location but when I call it in the `.get` request it returns undefined. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and any guidance would be a great help!

```
   router.get('/api/search/:location', async (req, res) => {
    const searchLocation = req.params.location;

    const geocode_res = await geocode(searchLocation, ({ latitude, longitude }) => {
       searchFunction(latitude, longitude)
    })

    console.log(geocode_res)
    res.send(geocode_res)
    
})
```

```
    module.exports = {
    async searchFunction(latitude, longitude){
        const URL = `https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}&maxradiuskm=50`
        try {
            let results = await axios.get(URL)
            return results.data.features
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`${err}`)
        }
    },

        async geocode(location, callback) {
        try{
            const GEO_URL = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${location}.json?access_token=${process.env.MAPBOX_API}`;
            let results = await axios.get(GEO_URL)
            const latLong = results.data.features[0].center
            callback({
                        latitude: latLong[1],
                        longitude: latLong[0]
                    })

        }catch(error){
            console.log(` ${error}`)
        }
    
    },

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `searchFunction` is an `async` function, you need to call it with `await`. And `await` can only be called inside an `async` function, thats why you need to make your `callback` an `async` function.

Also, you need to do `return` from the callback

**Try this:**

```
const geocode_res = await geocode(searchLocation, async ({ latitude, longitude }) => {
   return await searchFunction(latitude, longitude)
})
```

You also need to return from your geocode function. so that returned value can be populated in `geocode_res`

```
async geocode(location, callback) {
    try{
        const GEO_URL = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${location}.json?access_token=${process.env.MAPBOX_API}`;
        let results = await axios.get(GEO_URL)
        const latLong = results.data.features[0].center
        // add return here
        return callback({
                    latitude: latLong[1],
                    longitude: latLong[0]
                })

    }catch(error){
        console.log(` ${error}`)
    }

},
```

Comment: Returning from the callback won't do anything, look at how it's used.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this and it won't work,  it will still return undefined

Comment: Sorry but you also need to do `return callback()` in geocode function. I have updated my code, please try that.